# Вывод потока stdout в консоль от child_process.execSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

Столкнулся с необходимостью запуска внешнего процесса из нодовского скрипта. Допустим внешний процесс запускается командой

```
 yarn install
```

В нодовском модуле `child_process` есть неблокирующий метод `exec`, с помощью коллбэка которого я могу видеть ошибки

```
exec('yarn install', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) console.log(error.code)
})
```

Однако, мне нужно, чтобы операция выполнялась синхронно, для чего я использую `execSync`,

```
execSync('yarn install')
```

который уже не выводить в консоль никаких сообщений.

Как получить поток вывода?

Comment: А какой из выходных потоков вы хотите получать: stdout или stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) позволяет задавать произвольные потоки `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` через параметр `stdio`.

Например, если вы хотите перенаправить содержимое `stdout` порождаемого процесса в `stdout` родительского процесса, то можно использовать вот такой код:

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
execSync('ls -l ~', {stdio: ['ignore', process.stdout, 'ignore']});
```

Подробнее о параметре `stdio` можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio).

Comment: И к тому же, `execSync` возвращает буфер с содержимым `stdout` выполненного процесса.

Comment: @Yaant, верно. Но буфер будет доступен только по окончанию выполнения дочернего процесса, а кастомный stdout будет наполняться сразу при получении данных.

Comment: отлично! спасибо. а если мы будем использовать третий аргумент `child.stderr`, это будет сообщение об ошибке от самого execSync? и можно ли перенаправить поток в файл?

Comment: Да, третий аргумент - это stderr. И да, его можно перенаправить в файл. О том, как создать поток записи в файл написано в документации к [fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну, это было просто дополнение для полноты картины. :) Так-то понятно, что использование `stdio` дает большую гибкость.